# Best practice to send response in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm coding REST APIs in Spring Boot. I want to make sure that my code is readable to front-end developers using Swagger API development tool ([Swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/)). For example

```
@GetMapping("/getOne")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOne(@RequestParam String id) {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<Branch>(branchService.getOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<FindError>(new FindError(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

If the request is successful, response is a ***Branch object***, if fails, the response is a ***FindError object*** which has only one attribute (**message**). So both can be carried out depends on the response. But the swagger UI doesn't show how the response should be shown, because I use **"?"** as **generic type**. Is this a best practice to catch an error? (This coding documentation Swagger is not useful to front-end developers since it doesn't show the response object). Or any best practice for the above problem?

There are a lot of method which return different object like **Branch**.

Comment: That's a horrible design, use proper http response code to indicate error conditions.

Comment: @varman Controllers should not return ambiguous types. It creates a lot of issues in the front-end and is generally considered as bad design. You should look into ResponseEntityExceptionHandler for handling error responses.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all you should follow the best practices of a RESTful API . Don't use verbs, instead use nouns as URL.So instead of `@GetMapping("/getOne")` , you can write
it as `@GetMapping("/branch/{id}")` .
You can refer this blog https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

@2ndly , Don't return a generic type as **?** , instead you can user the specific type , here as **Branch** and do central exception handling .
The following code snippet can help you :

```
@GetMapping("/branch/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Branch> getBranch(@Pathvariable String id) {
{
    Branch branch = branchService.getOne(id);

    if(branch == null) {
         throw new RecordNotFoundException("Invalid Branch id : " + id);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Branch>(branch, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**RecordNotFoundException.java**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecordNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
{
    public RecordNotFoundException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    }
}
```

**CustomExceptionHandler.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RecordNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleRecordNotFoundException(RecordNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Record Not Found", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**ErrorResponse.java**

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    private String message;

    private List<String> details;

    //Getter and setters
}
```

The  above class handles multiple exceptions including RecordNotFoundException and you can also customize for payload validations too.

**Test Cases :**

```
1) HTTP GET /branch/1 [VALID]

HTTP Status : 200

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Branch 1",
    ...
}
2) HTTP GET /branch/23 [INVALID]

HTTP Status : 404

{
    "message": "Record Not Found",
    "details": [
        "Invalid Branch id : 23"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, but if I get any other errors, will Exception.class handle it? Eg: Hibernate validation...

Comment: Yes it will handle.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do it like this .

```
@GetMapping("/getOne")
public Response getOne(@RequestParam String id) {
        ResponseEntity<Branch> resbranch;
        ResponseEntity<FindError> reserror;
        try {
            resbranch=new ResponseEntity<Branch>(branchService.getOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
            return Response.status(200).entity(resbranch).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            reserror=new ResponseEntity<FindError>(new FindError(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            return Response.status(400).entity(reserror).build();
        }
    }
```

200 is for OK and 400 is for bad request. Here there wont be anymore ambiguous types..