# return different type of response from controller when there is an error state

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How do I handle error states inside a controller?

For example: My controller which accepts two headers. If both the headers are null then it's a problem so return response of type `ErrorResponse` else if all ok then return response of type `customer`.

However, there is a problem as we defined the handler method to return `ResponseEntity<Customer>`.

My controller:

```
@PostMapping("/generate/send")
fun handleRequest( @RequestHeader header1: String,
                    @RequestHeader header2: String): ResponseEntity<Customer> {
     
    if(header1 == null && header2== null) { // ERROR if both header null
      
        return ResponseEntity(ErrorResponse(""), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST )
    }

    return ResponseEntity(Customer(), HttpStatus.OK )
}
```

how do refactor my code to prevent this or handle this type of situation where I have to return a different type because of an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ResponseEntity<?>` to return either `Customer` or `ErrorResponse` like this.

```
@PostMapping("/generate/send")
fun handleRequest( @RequestHeader header1: String,
                    @RequestHeader header2: String): ResponseEntity<?> {
       // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to use ResponseEntity<?> ?

Comment: If you can avoid generic type is the best way. You can throw an error instead of `return` and return only `Customer`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55791293/13464279) answer.